# How can I extract pictures from a WBC file in C?

Tags: c, image, extract

Someone ask me to help them extract their pictures from a Web Shots image collection file (.WBC).  I tried XnView but it did not work. How can I do this in C?

Comment: So what is the question? Looks more like an answer than a question to me.

Comment: I answered the question.  Hopefully, if someone "googles" the question then they will get this answer.

Comment: @Mike - I've moved the answer. If you copy it to your own answer I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4778/mike):

> I hacked together some code to do the job.  Here it is.  It's not production quality code, so if you do not understand it then do not run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void save_image(const char* filename, FILE* in_fp)
{
   char buf[4096];
   size_t read;
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
   if (!fp) {
      fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file.");
      exit(1);
   }
   do {
      read = fread(buf,1,sizeof(buf),in_fp);
      fwrite(buf, 1, read, fp);
   } while (read);
   fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char buf[4096];
   unsigned int read, read_tot = 0;
   FILE *fp;
   int image_count = 1;
   char filename[255];
   unsigned int i;

   char pattern[] = "JFIF";
   int pi = 0;

   long int curpos;
   char pad[50];

   char src_filename[] = 
       "C:\\Documents and Settings\\mikeking\\Desktop\\WBC\\"
       "Custom - CATHYS WEDDING.wbc";
   char des_directory[] = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\mikeking\\Desktop\\F\\";

   fp = fopen(src_filename, "rb");
   if (!fp) {
      fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file.");
      exit(1);
   }

   do {
      read = fread(buf,1,sizeof(buf),fp);

      for(i=0; i<read; i++){
         if (buf[i] == pattern[pi]) {
            pi++;
            if (pi == sizeof(pattern)) {
               strcpy(filename, des_directory);
               itoa(image_count, pad, 10);
               image_count++;
               strcat(filename, pad);
               strcat(filename, ".jpg");
               curpos = ftell(fp);
               fseek(fp,read_tot+i-10,SEEK_SET);
               save_image(filename,fp);
               fseek(fp,curpos,SEEK_SET);
            }
         } else {
          pi = 0;
         }
      }
      read_tot += read;
   } while (read);

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```